# Using Continuity to control secondary Macbook, is it possible to map a keyboard shortcut to shift focus to other machine?

Tags: macos, continuity

It seems that the only way to obtain focus on the other machine (so that keypresses are interpreted there, rather than the machine being typed on), is to move the mouse across to the other display and click. It would be nice if you could do this without having to move the mouse.

I tried using hammerspoon to  a key to shift to focus the next display but that doesn't seem to work with Continuity.